# How to master regular expression, especially in multiple language

Tags: regex

I always want to master regular expression, although it isn't encouraged to use in many scenarios. But regex is a neat tool for occasional use. Everytime I need regex i spent lot time on cheat sheet or stackexchange. I try to read few book but most of them don't have enough example. And the regex seems to be slightly different in different languages. I can't write it in java after switching from writing it in python. I'm wondering is there any good way to master the regex? Any recommendation will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this book "Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd Edition by Jeffrey E.F. Friedl " really helpful in understanding regular expression. You can get your copy [here](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do)

In initial chapters, book details the syntax to write regular expression.
Last four chapters are really helpful in using regular expression in different languages like a> Perl b> Java c> .NET d> PHP

This is one of the useful tool to test the regular expression online. You can find it [here](http://regex101.com/)